# Conver integer to float with pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a series of numbers, and I need them to transform something like this:

```
3565 > 35.65

123 > 1.23

43 > 0.43

2 > 0.02
```

How can i Do This?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/5699329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert the number to string, add a dot and convert it back to float.

```js
function convertToFloat(num) {

        const stringNumArr  = `${num}`.split('');
        // prepend 0s if the number has less than three chanracters
        while (stringNumArr.length < 3) {
          stringNumArr.unshift(0);
        }

        const floatString = `${stringNumArr.slice(0, stringNumArr.length - 2).join('')}.${stringNumArr.slice(-2).join('')}`;

        const floatNum = +floatString
        console.log(floatNum);

}

convertToFloat(3645);
convertToFloat(123);
convertToFloat(12);
convertToFloat(1);
```